I am using BioOracle data and reducing it to 1 point per cell but when I try to covert to a sf grid, I end up having issues
I am using multiple BioOracle layers as geotiff files and reducing it to 1 point per cell, but when I try to convert to an SF grid, I end up having issues. I keep receiving an error stating:

Error in st_as_sf(): ! Must group by variables found in
.data. ✖ Column ID is not found.

Here is my code:
# Utilize a ggllay (ggpairs) to make correlations to test -----------------
#
# Read geotiff files
sst_bo_585 <- raster("./data/bo_SST_SSP585_terra.tif")
so_bo_585 <- raster("./data/bo_SO_SSP585_terra.tif")
sws_bo_585 <- raster("./data/bo_SWS_SSP585_terra.tif")
phyc_bo_585 <- raster("./data/bo_phyc_SSP585_terra.tif")

grid <- raster::rasterToPolygons(raster::raster(xmn = -180,
                                                xmx = 180,
                                                ymn = -90,
                                                ymx = 90,
                                                resolution = 1))
plot(grid)
#
# Use sf (simple features) ------------------------------------------------
#
sf_grid <- st_as_sf(grid, wkt = "geometry")
sf_grid$ID <- 1:nrow(grid)
points_sf <- st_as_sf(sf_grid, coords = c("decimalLongitude", "decimalLatitude"), crs = 4326)
join_data <- st_join(points_sf, sf_grid, join = st_within)
# Reduce to 1 ppc
oppc <- join_data %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  sample_n(1) %>% 
  ungroup()

